# Horizontal alignment via css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontal align some content via CSS.

```
<asp:Label ID="idWelcome" runat="server" style="position:absolute; margin-left:40%"></asp:Label>        
<asp:Label ID="idName" runat="server" style="position:absolute; margin-left:80%">Name</asp:Label>
```

Can someone tell me what style should i add so the label Welcome is showed in the right corner no matter what is the resolution of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using absolute position:

```
position:absolute;
right: 0; 
top: 0;

<asp:Label ID="idWelcome" runat="server" style="position:absolute; right:0"></asp:Label>
```

You can learn more about positioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Both. PLease check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `right` property of the element which is `position:absolute`

```
<asp:Label ID="idWelcome" runat="server" style="position:absolute; right:0"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to position the 'Welcome ..' text in the top right at all time you should definitely use the CSS position:fixed; attribute but first, wrap it with a DIV so you also include the name then position the div in the top right corner:

```
<div id="wrap-div">
  <asp:Label ID="idWelcome" runat="server"></asp:Label>        
  <asp:Label ID="idName" runat="server">Name</asp:Label>
</div>

#wrap-div{
  postion: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

When you want it to position in the top right, but want it to dissapear on scroll, use position: absolute; and make sure the element in which the wrap-div is positioned, covers the top-right corner. Position it like this:

```
#warp-div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :-

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
    <asp:Label ID="idWelcome" runat="server"></asp:Label>        
    <asp:Label ID="idName" runat="server">Name</asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: How abt down voting this?